# Android Studio not adding RecyclerView library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just installed android studio and when I go Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add Library, I pick RecyclerView like many times before set it to compile and hit ok. Usually I would see something like syncing with gradle but now nothing. When I enter dependencies again there is no RecyclerView at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio go to File-> Project Structure.
in "app" section choose "Dependencies" click on "+" icon and choose "Library dependencies" find "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1" or latest lib from that list.
It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Do a gradle sync.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gradile scripts->Build gradle(Module: app)

add below statement inside dependencies{}
compile **'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'**

Then sync gradle.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to add dependency in Android Studio
Firstly click on File on Left Top Corner
Open File->Project Structure

There is Modules of your app selected in Left Partition of Window
In right side select dependencies and click on plus button as in image and search any dependency which you want.[Clcik on plus image for add dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2C1.png)